# How to remove the ending sign from Bangla Text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

```
লোকাল ট্রেন পরিষেবা চালু করার জন্য দীর্ঘদিন ধরেই সরব হয়েছেন বহু নেতা নেত্রী।
```

How can I remove the **"|"** sign from the Bangla Sentence?
and then tokenize it?

in this format "নেত্রী" instead of "নেত্রী।"

I am using python language.

Comment: Does `str.rstrip` not work?

Comment: If you need to remove, did you try `.replace('|', '')`? What is the problem you have when  tokenizing the string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 
Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the ending "।", you can use string `.replace()` method: `sentence.replace('।', '')`.

To tokenize the sentence, there are many libraries available, you can use any of [`inltk`](https://github.com/goru001/inltk), [`indicnlp`](http://anoopkunchukuttan.github.io/indic_nlp_library/), [`stanfordnlp`](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/), [`bnlp`](https://bnlp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here's a complete example using `bnlp`:

```py
from bnlp import NLTKTokenizer

bnltk = NLTKTokenizer()

sentence = "লোকাল ট্রেন পরিষেবা চালু করার জন্য দীর্ঘদিন ধরেই সরব হয়েছেন বহু নেতা নেত্রী।"
sentence = sentence.replace('।', '') // remove ending "।"
word_tokens = bnltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```